# Installing a .sh and .sh.part file

Tags: software-installation, mathematica

I want to install Mathematica 11, a version from my university. I have two files, Mathematica11_1_1_LINUX.sh and Mathematica11_1_1_LINUX.sh.part.

What do I have to do in order to install the program?

Comment: From a directory of my uni. I click at "Mathematica11_1_1_LINUX.sh", save the file at Downloads and have the two (.sh and .sh.part) files in my Downloads folder. I wondered that that was that quick because Mathematica must be a huge file..

Comment: The .sh file has 0B and the .sh.part file has 733.5 MiB.

Comment: Yes, they are the same

Comment: The size should be 4.2G.

Comment: Now, the size of the .part file becomes bigger.

Answer (score 2):

Some Web browsers, when asked to download a file `f`, will:

- immediately create an empty file `f`;
- write the data, as it arrives, to `f.part`;
- once all of the data has been received, rename `f.part` to `f`.

If you see both a `.sh.part` and an empty `.sh` file, it means that your download is probably still ongoing. When it completes, you will want to execute the `.sh` file (perhaps by running `sh Mathematica11_1_1_LINUX.sh`, in your specific case).